# Apache Kafka Consumer Group Example Across Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka, I have implemented KAFKA cluster across 3 servers, and in 3 Servers I am running Consumers each Server having 3 consumers, i.e.. 3x3 =9 Consumers.

My Question is :- 
 1. When I give Same group ID across the Cluster for same Topic I am not receiving any duplicate messages but when I give 3 different consumers group IDs across the Cluster for the Same topic I am  receiving Duplicate messages exactly 3?

Please help how to use Consumer Groups?

Comment: this is how kafka works. same group -> multiple partition in kafka -> records divided among those consumers; consumers with different groups will read the same records. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I think the following analogy may help understand the concept. Consider a new employee is joining your firm. So you have an `employees` topic. 
Now, this employee has to visit the IT department to get all the equipment (computer etc.), it has to meet the security department to get his employee tag and undergo briefing, he has to meet someone from HR to hear about proper conduct and company policy etc.

Now IT department has 5 workers (5 consumers), HR has 4 workers (4 consumers) and security guy is a one man's show (single consumer). 
So you have 3 consumer groups, each of them has to handle all new employees, so each employee is handled 3 times.

Now introducing the partitioning concept - you put the employees in lines (partitions). Each partition is handled by a single consumer of each consumer group (that's kafka limitation). So say you have 20 lines of employees. Each IT guy is handling 4 lines, each HR guy is handling 5 lines, and poor security guy is handling all 20 lines.

hope it clarifies a bit...

Answer (score 0):

The whole reason for having a GroupId is so that the consumers in that group will work together, i.e. not consuming the same messages.

Having a consumer group means that you can divide the work of consuming between multiple consumers = performance gain.

Without a group id, the consumers act as completely separate consumers, so they each read all the messages.